# remove foreground from segmented image

Tags: python, opencv

i have trained a model to provide the segment in image and the output image looks like that [image]

the original image is like that [image]

i have tried opencv to subtract the two images by

```
image1 = imread("cristiano-ronaldo.jpg")
image2 = imread("cristiano-ronaldo_seg.png")



image3 = cv2.absdiff(image1,image2)
```

but the output is not what i need , i would like to have cristiano and white background , how i can achieve that

Comment: you can loop over the pixels, whenever you get a `black` in the trained model. you set the original pictures alpha  to 0.

Comment: you mean to change in the model it self or using opencv ?
i would to to the operation on this two images , can you please provide a code sample that illustrate the idea of overlapping pixels

Comment: Are your images going to be alway the same size in that fashion?

Comment: yes , same size always and the pixel color will be the differentiator

Comment: Have written you an explanation and solution in the Answers section

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Explanation:**
As your files have already the right shape `(BGR)` and `(A)` it is very easy to accomplish what you are trying to do, here are the steps.

1) Load original image as **BGR** (In opencv it's reversed rgb)

2) Load "mask" image as a single Channel **A**

3) Merge the original images `BGR` channel and consume your mask image as `A` Alpha

**Code:**

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

# Load an color image in grayscale
img1 = cv2.imread('ronaldo.png',3) #READ BGR

img2 = cv2.imread('ronaldoMask.png',0) #READ AS ALPHA
kernel = np.ones((2,2), np.uint8) #Create Kernel for the depth
img2 = cv2.erode(img2, kernel, iterations=2) #Erode using Kernel

width, height, depth = img1.shape
combinedImage = cv2.merge((img1, img2))



cv2.imwrite('ronaldocombine.png',combinedImage)
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: Thanks, it works is there any way to remove one pixel from every direction in the mask to get better results

Comment: There are two image filters called erode And dilate

Comment: Edited the answer including erosion.

Answer (score 3):

After read the segment image, convert to grayscale, then threshold it to get `fg-mask` and `bg-mask`. Then use `cv2.bitwise_and` to "crop" the fg or bg as you want.

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
# 2017.11.26 09:56:40 CST
# 2017.11.26 10:11:40 CST
import cv2
import numpy as np

## read 
img = cv2.imread("img.jpg")
seg = cv2.imread("seg.png")

## create fg/bg mask 
seg_gray = cv2.cvtColor(seg, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
_,fg_mask = cv2.threshold(seg_gray, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY|cv2.THRESH_OTSU)
_,bg_mask = cv2.threshold(seg_gray, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV|cv2.THRESH_OTSU)

## convert mask to 3-channels
fg_mask = cv2.cvtColor(fg_mask, cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)
bg_mask = cv2.cvtColor(bg_mask, cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)

## cv2.bitwise_and to extract the region
fg = cv2.bitwise_and(img, fg_mask)
bg = cv2.bitwise_and(img, bg_mask)

## save 
cv2.imwrite("fg.png", fg)
cv2.imwrite("bg.png", bg)
```

---

[image]